# Flutter Deeplinking issue in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, redirect, path, deep-linking

While hit the url from browser it directly open the APP. We have created webview on domain side that first verify the user and then press the button, after pressing the button user have to navigate to the app by using pathprefix but pathprefix is not working it directly open the app which is not correct!

[image]

I have configure the deeplinking on APP side.

And I have set the **apple-app-site-association** file as

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "apps": [],
      "details": [
      {
        "appID": "S*****3.com.example.deeplink",
        "paths": ["*", "NOT /verify-email/*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But still not working.
I need to navigate user from website though pathprefix to APP. I jusdt need to navigate the urls that ends with **/login** and **/job** only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following solution **NOT*** means it will not route all the path, It will only route the path end with **/login** or contain **/login** and **/job**, /* means the path contains defined keys, like **[www.abc.com/login/a](http://www.abc.com/login/a)*******.

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "TEAMID.APP-BundleID",
            "paths": ["/login","/login/*", "/job/*", "NOT *"]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

By this, you can navigate to the app by hitting direct links like:
**[www.abc.com/login](http://www.abc.com/login)** or **[www.abc.com/login/b](http://www.abc.com/login/b)******* or **[www.abc.com/job/c](http://www.abc.com/job/c)*******

if you hit this URL on the browser there will be a top banner of that app suggesting you open it.
[Popup for open App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65oI4.jpg)

**NOTE:** After updating the *apple-app-site-association* file it may take 24 to 48 hours to render the changes and you need to clear the Safari cache before using deep linking.